# why my "recepie" category is not taken into account in my request

Tags: php, jquery

hello why my "recipe" category is not taken into account in my request

```
<?php
// 1. We define the arguments to define what we want to recover
$args = array (
   'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '16',
    'category_name' => 'recipe',
);

// 2. We run the WP Query
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query ($args);

// 3. we display the number of messages and the authors!
// The Loop
if ($the_query-> have_posts()) {
    //Set arguments to grab all authors with published peches, and order them by user ID
    $authorArgs = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'has_published_posts' => array('post'),
    );

    //Create an array of all authors with peches published
    $pecheAuthors = get_users($authorArgs);

    //Loop through each peche author
    foreach($pecheAuthors as $user){
        //Output user post count 
        echo'<font color="#f00;"><b>';
        echo count_user_posts($user->ID, 'post');
        echo'</b></font>';
        echo ' journees de pêches pour ';

        //Output user's display name
        echo'<font color="#f00;"><b>';
        echo $user->display_name;
        echo'</b></font>';
        echo '<br />';
    }

    // 3. We launch the loop to display the articles and the authors!
    // The Loop
    
} else {
    // no posts found
}
//wp_reset_postdata ();?
?>
```

Comment: In your question and your code, you've spelled "repecie" and "repcie" two different ways. I'd check to make sure you're matching the category name exactly as it appears in your Categories. You could try using the category ID as well instead of the category name.

Is recipe a custom post type or just a category? I know a lot of sites create a custom post type for their recipes.

Comment: Thank you for the remark with the category name.
i tried with the category id, but the result is the same.
The category is not taken into account
The category is indeed a category of posts

Answer (score 1):

This explicit code is missing from your example and you should verify that you have at least these statements (plus any additional post tag functions, or analogous calls to "the_content()") included exactly as this in your original code:

```
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
       the_content();
   endwhile;
```

This should roughly be at the location noted by this comment in your code:

```
    // The Loop
```

If your while statement is not specifically calling methods of $the_query, that would call up a default query that has already been run and that does not match your category query.

Comment: Hello
thank you for the answer
I just have to add the piece of code mentioned to my request after // The Loop